Why would you need to define a series as an ordered pair?
I've seen a series defined formally as an ordered pair of sequences $(a_n,s_n)$, such that $s_0=a_0$ and $s_{n}=s_{n-1}+a_n$. I was wondering why would you define it this way, like what is the convenience or the need for this definition. Also, it seems pretty redundant, since the sequence $a_n$ can be derived from $s_n$ regardless.

How would you define a series?

This is definitely not needed, and honestly I don't find it convenient at all. It's rather confusing.

@ThomasAndrews as a sequence $s_n$ such that there exists a sequence $a_n$ such that $s_0=a_0$ and $s_n=s_{n-1}+a_n$. I would call its limit the sum of the series.

This just seems like one possible way of deriving one sequence ($s_n$) from another sequence ($a_n$), somewhat analogous to how you derive $f’(x)$ from $f(x)$. What is it about this that seems problematic to you? It’s not at all clear to me from the question as it’s written.

Are you under the impression that that every series has to be defined this way? If so, I suspect you have misunderstood something that you read.

As you observe, the sequence $\{a_n\}$ can be derived from $\{s_n\}$, and the opposite is also true, so it's certainly redundant. But it also, in any theorem, gives a name to both the things you'll care about, so you can write things like "If $(a_n, s_n)$ and $(b_n, t_n)$ are convergent series with sums $S$ and $T$, then so is $(a_n + b_n, s_n + t_n)$, with sum $S + T$." (I'm being very informal here and skipping braces and limits like $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ for the sake of getting to the point.)
Students often get hung up on names, and think that the terms in ANY sequence have to be called "$a_n$", and the partial sums have to be called "$s_n$", etc., so this is a real convenience. It also makes clear that although with the conventional definition of a series (the one where you just list the $a_n$, but with plus-signs between them) you've got the sequence of individual terms, there's also a second sequence (the partial sums) that we're interested in, and it puts that second sequence front-and-center.
On the other hand, it also introduces an obligation during proofs. You can't just pair up any two things and call the result a series! In the preceding "theorem", it was important that the partial sums $s_n + t_n$ really ARE the partial sums of the sequence-terms, $a_n + b_n$. So one has to prove, at the start of the proof of that theorem, that $(a_n + b_n, s_n + t_n)$ is a series, and then prove that it is convergent.
All in all, it's probably not a bad thing to do pedagogically, although it obviously has the potential to be confusing (or you wouldn't have asked your question!).
Whether pedagogy was the intent of the person who used that definition wherever you read it ... well, that's a matter of conjecture, but it sure seems likely to me.

To me, this seems analogous to defining a function $f\colon X\to Y$ as a set of ordered pairs in $X\times Y$ with particular properties.
We could ask “why do we need to define a function this way, since we know what a function is supposed to be doing and we can just recover the output from the input?”. But if we want to formalize all the mathematics we use in terms of set theory, some definition like the above is needed. (for a time, while studying foundations, but then we don't think of that definition going forward in our daily lives)
I have the same reaction to this definition of a series, which I really think of as an operation on sequences rather than an object ... but that's what I think of the squaring function too, so here we are.

It's not analogous at all. Given the set of inputs (the domain), you can't determine the outputs uniquely. Instead, given $a_n$ there is only one $s_n$ such that $(a_n,s_n)$ is a series.
